# Как правильно реализовать заглушку для RecyclerView во время загрузки в Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Происходит загрузка данных, которые потом отображаются в RecyclerView. Так вот, во время этой загрузки не хочется показывать ProgressBar, хочется реализовать типа такого как на картинке. Буду рад любой помощи.[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Этот паттерн называется Skeleton. Погуглите, в сети полно библиотек для его реализации

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, взял вот эту библиотеку https://github.com/ethanhua/Skeleton

Comment: Ахах) Мы юзаем эту же либу на проде